# How to send already existing object with postman?

Tags: postman

I got 2 entities, Student [saved in 'students' table at DB] and Grade [saved in 'grades' table at DB].

Student is a field of Grade. [each Grade has a Student its belong to]

I added a Student Object to my DB, and now I want to add a Grade Object, but I dont know the syntax for it.. (Im using POSTMAN)

Thanks for your help :)

Here my Student object in JSON:

```
{"fullName":"Idan","age":"25"} //get id '1' in my DB
    Added successfully !
```

Here is my Grade object:

```
  {  "student"  :
        { "$ref":"students", 
          "$id" : "ObjectId('1')" 
        } ..
   }
```

its seems Im using the wrong syntax.

Comment: So your question is about how to use postman and how to reference objects between calls?